# How to read the <strong> text and the link url using DOMdocument?

Tags: php

I have this html:

```
<a href=" URL TO KEEP" class="class_to_check">
<strong> TEXT TO KEEP</strong>
</a>
```

I have a long html code with many link as above, I have to keep the links that have the `<strong>` inside, I have to keep the HREF of the link and the text inside the `<strong>`, how can i do using `DOMDocument`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = "...";
$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new XPath($dom);

$a = $xp->query('//a')->item(0);
$href = $a->getAttribute('href');
$strong = $a->nodeValue;
```

Of course, this XPath stuff works for just this particular html snippet. You'll have to adjust it to work with a more fully populated HTML tree.

Comment: I was about to suggest XPath :)

Comment: guys, how can i print an entire NODE to see what html code there is inside?

Comment: DOMDocument doesn't have a native .innerHTML type setup, but you can fake it, as per this comment on the PHP site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#105815